# Jboss is not running on browser while giving the URL http://127.0.0.1:8080 in browser

Tags: server

i have installed jboss 6.1.1 after installing i have restarted JBoss it got started in 4m:56s but if i am giving url http://127.0.0.1:8080 in browser it is showing HTTP 404 not found

Comment: are you sure jboss is running on port 8080?

Comment: sorry Floriah jboss is running on 8010 and yeah my problem is resolved

Comment: if you have solved the problem it would be nice if you could post your solution as answer, so other users facing the same problem have a better chance

Comment: Actually problem was coming beause of jndi name i have not given the correct jndi name in standalone xml